# Fetch all the valid JSON strings from a text String in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a situation where in some JSON strings are seperated by a comma. For example I have a string which looks like this

> `{Valid JSON String},{Valid JSON String},{Valid JSON String}`

I want to fetch each valid JSON string and store them in a ArrayList. How do I break the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
List<JSONObject> result = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
String s = "{Valid JSON String},{Valid JSON String},{Valid JSON String}";
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("[" + s + "]");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    result.add(arr.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

An then, with each `JSONObject`, you can do whatever you want